# compare the auc of four ROC curves in r

Tags: r, roc, auc

I want to compare the auc of four roc curves in R. 
I tried `roc.test` , but this function can just compare two curves

```
roc.test(roc1,roc2)
```

Does R have a function to compare four curves?
I know in stata I can compare 4 curves by `roccomp`. Does any one know how to compare four curves in R?

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Stata's `roccomp` function. What are looking for exactly, a table with the AUC and 95% confidence intervals, a plot, a p value (with which H0)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think its there with roc.test but you can use `library(caTools)` to do it.

It is very easy to compare AUC values like below by using **'sapply'** using `library(pROC)` as well, I am describing both the methods here:

**Example and Setup for both the methods**:

**Building the model here:**

```
    lm1 <- lm(am ~ disp + mpg, data= mtcars)
    lm2 <- lm(am ~ disp + hp, data= mtcars)
    lm3 <- lm(am ~ disp + wt, data= mtcars)
```

**Predicting the model here:**

```
predict1 <- predict(lm1, newdata=mtcars)
predict2 <- predict(lm2, newdata=mtcars)
predict3 <- predict(lm3, newdata=mtcars)
```

### **Method1:**

```
library("caTools")
colAUC(cbind(predict1, predict2, predict3), mtcars$am, plotROC = T)
```

**Output:**

```
                 [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
    0 vs. 1 0.8380567 0.9433198 0.9433198
```

If you choose to use `plotROC = T` then you will receive a plot comparison between the ROCs

[image]

### **Method2:**

```
auc.val <- sapply(list(predict1, predict2, predict3),function(x)roc(pred=x,resp=mtcars$am)$auc)
```

**Finally calculating the AUC using sapply here:**

```
library(pROC)
auc.val <- sapply(list(predict1, predict2, predict3),function(x)roc(pred=x,resp=mtcars$am)$auc)
```

would return this:

```
> auc.val
[1] 0.8380567 0.9433198 0.9433198
```

In case you are interested printing this with names , use `USE.NAMES` in sapply

```
> auc.val <- sapply(list("lm1" = predict1, "lm2" = predict2,"lm3"= predict3),function(x)roc(pred=x,resp=mtcars$am)$auc, USE.NAMES = T)
> auc.val
      lm1       lm2       lm3 
0.8380567 0.9433198 0.9433198
```